# Formal Linux Kernel Memory Model

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, memory-model

images and citations comes from:
[Frightening Small Children and Disconcerting Grown-ups: Concurrency in the Linux Kernel](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/323935595)

Let's consider a simple program:

[image: 2]

`cumul-fence` is defined as:

```
cumul-fence := A-cumul(strong-fence ∪ po-rel) ∪ wmb
A-cumul(r)  := rfe';r
```

In the linked publication in 3.2.3 it is written that `(b, e) ∈ prop`. From that we can conclude that `(c, d) ∈ cumul-fence`.

So, let's see:

```
po-rel = {(c,d)}
strong-fence = {(a,b),(e,f)}
wmb = {}
rfe = {(d,e)}
rfe' = {(d,d), (d,e), (e,e)} <- reflexive closure of rfe. 
A-cumul({(a,b),(e,f),(c,d)}) = {(d,d), (d,e), (e,e)};{(a,b),(e,f),(c,d)} = {(d,f), (e,f)}
cumul-fence = {(d,f), (e,f)}
```

so, as we can see `(c,d)` is not in `cumul-fence`. Can someone explain me where my reasoning is incorrect?

Comment: I would like to learn your notation better. If you have some time, would you briefly explain? I assume that `U` means union/or, but what is the apostrophe `'`? Negation? Also, words like "cumul" and "reflexive closure" are opaque to me, though they sound smart. The reason I ask is that words and symbols of this kind appear neither in the kernel source nor in the manufacturer's x86 documentation as far as I know (neither are they in RFCs or other docs I read), so one would like to learn more about them.

Comment: @thb: I think cumul = cumulative, but most of the rest of the terminology is opaque to me, too.  I guess we'll have to read the linked paper and/or learn the `cat` language to understand it :P

Comment: @PeterCordes: I believe that I have seen notation of this kind. It's like something a graduate student in computer science would write. Because I took my master's degree decades ago, and since the degree—electrical engineering—was in the wrong major (where the mathematics goes in the direction of special functions rather than graph and category theory), I have unfortunately never been properly introduced to this sort of formalism. I wish that I could read it better, because it looks like it probably has value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rfe'`, the [reflexive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_closure) of `rfe`, is

```
{(d,e), (a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (d, d), (e, e), (f, f), (k, k), (r, r)}
```

since the set of nodes is `{a, b, c, d, e, f, k, r}`.

From there, `cumul-fence` is `{(d, f), (a, b), (c, d), (e, f)}`.

Comment: thanks! It means that I used wrong definition of reflexive closure. Your answer is obviously correct and helpful. However, why do you skip `{k, r}` in the set of nodes? It seems to be sensible to skip memory barriers because treat them as events is quirky. But, can you explain?

Comment: @Gilgamesz Oh, you are right. I must have mentally skipped them due to some reason. I'll correct the answer. `k` and `r` doesn't appear to influence `cumul-fence` in this case, though.